# Replacing string via sed failing regardless of delimiter

Tags: linux, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to inject a Jenkins param to a YAML file by substituting a dummy value with the database URL encoded as base64 but is failing by throwing: **char 95: unterminated `s' command**.

My variable looks like this:

```
env.DB_URL="jdbc:mariadb://mydb:3306/postservice?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;useSSL=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"
```

Here's what I tried:

```
sed -e "s/dumyvalue/$(echo ${DB_URL} | base64)/" ./file.yaml
```

I tried to escape all characters including '/','&',';' but still no success. Also, I changed the delimiter to '#', same problem.

Expected results inside file.yaml:

**database_url**: dummyvalue should become **database_url**: db url base64 encoded

Works fine with strings without slashes.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but your variable is called `env.DB_URL` and in the sed command you're echoing `${DB_URL}`. Should it be `${env.DB_URL}` instead?

Comment: @mattb env. is not necessary since the password and username are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the spaces generated by the output of `$(echo $DB_URL | base64)`. Therefore, you could take a 2-step approach: First,
sanitise the variable (by escaping the spaces for sed) before doing the
substitution like so:

```
sanitised=$(echo $(echo $DB_URL | base64) | sed 's/ //g')
```

then 2) you can use it in the sed command: this should do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/dumyvalue/'"$sanitised"'/' ./file.yaml
```

Comment: just spotted a typo, now removed, (it was a random 'l' in the second command just after the `"$santised"`

Comment: it works. Thanks man. For space deletion I added this "s/ //g" since s/\s/\\ /g didn't work on jenkins

Comment: Ah cool! Glad it helped! I updated the answer using the the `s/ //g` way.